# Rails 4 - coffee script not working properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

The goal is to change icons on click. It's a simple thumbs up icons for comments.

show file

```
<a data-method="put" data-remote="true" href="/comments/1/like" rel="nofollow">

  <img alt="" src="/assets/othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG" 
  style="height: 20px; width: 20px" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"  />

</a>
```

coffeescript

```
$("#imgClickAndChange").click ->
  imagePath = $("#imgClickAndChange").attr("src")
  if imagePath is "/assets/othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG"
    $("#imgClickAndChange").attr "src", "/assets/othericons/thumbsup_on.PNG"
  else
    $("#imgClickAndChange").attr "src", "/assets/othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG"
  return
```

aplication.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery-simple-pagination-plugin
//= require jquery.raty
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: You have a jquery method AND a onclick method, both for clicking? Why? maybe remove one of them

Comment: What would you suggest? I tried removing onlick="...", but still the same problem continues.

Comment: not working properly, is the click function executed successfully?

Comment: No. When I click on it, image doesn't change. I tried different scripts, but I think the problem might be somewhere else in the rails code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use this code:

```
<img alt="" src="/assets/othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG" 
  style="height: 20px; width: 20px" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="window.changeImage($(this))"  />

:coffeescript
  window.changeImage = (source) ->
    console.log "called changeImage(source)"
    $source = $(source)
    imagePath = $source.attr("src")
    if imagePath && imagePath == "/assets/othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG"
      console.log "thumbsup is currently OFF"
      $source.attr("src", "/assets/othericons/thumbsup_on.PNG")
    else
      console.log "thumbsup is currently ON"
      $source.attr("src", "/assets/othericons/thumbsup_off.PNG")
```

You should see messages in your console (f12 for Google Chrome browser, tab 'console'), if you don't see any of these messages, there is a problem with your JavaScript / Coffeescript.

**A little suggestion**:  rename your js function "changeImage()" to "toggleImage()", why? Because this function is actually toggling between 2 images (not less, not more).

Hope this helps!